# Scroll to bottom of div with jQuery-set content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

First of all, I really don't know much about JavaScript or jQuery, so sorry in advance for any stupid thing I could say :)

I have a div with a set height of which the content loads on page load using AJAX. My objective is to have it scrolled to the bottom on page load.

I've found a few answers on how to do this online, but none of these worked for a div of which the content is set with jQuery :/

Any ideas ?

Comment: Please, provide some code.

Comment: You may need to use something like this:
`var top = $("div").height();
$(window).load(function(){
$("div").scrollTop(height);
});`

Answer (score 0):

**OK !** Was going to upload my code when I found what the problem was :

The said div was inside another div, on which I had set `height: 750px` and `overflow: auto`, which worked perfectly as it was, but made jQuery unable to determine the height and scroll overflow of the child div. Fixed it, all works now !

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

You could add the below code after the ready function:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#yourid").offset().top   }, 1000);
```

Comment: Found what my problem was (posted it 20 minutes ago), but thanks for your help :)